# How to boot el6 linux without some enabled daemon running?

Tags: boot, daemon, oracle-linux

I've installed Oracle Linux 6 and Oracle 12c.

I don't remember if I've configured crontab to launch some script or not, but during the system's booting, it stops just after crond daemon has been started.

I've also tried booting with different kernels.

[image: System stops loading after crond daemon starting]

I could not access the system.

Is there a way to skip crond daemon starting without access to system configuration?

Comment: being rhel 6 with *sysinit* and not *systemd* you can skip `crond` during boot by having done a `chkconfig <service> off` then rebooting allowing the normal boot process.  You would need to first need to interrupt the normal boot and make it boot to single user mode to do `chkconfig crond off` then reboot allowing normal boot process to runlevel 3 or 5.

Comment: It seems that crond service is not responsible for this behavior. I've tried disabling it also, but it stops booting further after tuned service starting. Something else prevents system from proper booting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `crond` has started successfully: the problem might be with *whatever comes after crond.* Or it might be triggered by something `crond` starts up.

Note that `sshd` has already started and network parameters have already been set, so you should be able to login with SSH.

If that does not work, the kernel may be hung. To troubleshoot, interrupt the automatic boot at the GRUB menu, and add a boot option (e.g. `single`) to boot the system into a minimal state ("single user mode"), omitting services like `crond`.

After doing that, maybe first check `/var/log/messages`, just in case there is a problem that causes log messages to be recorded but fails to display them.

Classically, the start-up scripts in `/etc/rc3.d` would be executed in alphanumerical order and comparing your boot messages on your screenshot to the contents of `/etc/rc3.d` on my RHEL VM looks like the order does match... so, run `ls /etc/rc3.d` and see what scripts come after `S90crond` on your installation if you need to know what would be the next steps in the start-up process.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, I could log in through ssh. I've deleted crontab's record I've added earlier. After reboot booting stops at the same point. But it is good enough that I could move further. I was thinking that crond starts that script and it prevents further booting. But this thought of mine was wrong.